# R package equivalent to Matlab's gmdistribution.fit()

Tags: r, matlab, gaussian

Matlab contains the following function:

```
obj = gmdistribution.fit(X,k)
```

As shown on this [website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html).

Is there an R package that offers this functionality as well?

Comment: I googled "Gaussian mixture model in R" and [THIS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) was the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MClust package contains the function densityMclust which produces an object that contains parameter estimates for the fitted Gaussian mixture model along with the density itself. From the MClust manual:

> ```
> > densWaiting <- densityMclust(faithful$waiting)
> > summary(densWaiting, parameters = TRUE)
> -------------------------------------------------------
> Density estimation via Gaussian finite mixture modeling
> -------------------------------------------------------
> Mclust E (univariate, equal variance) model with 2 components:
> log.likelihood
> n df
> BIC
> -1034 272 4 -2090.4
> Clustering table:
> 1   2
> 99 173
> Mixing probabilities:
> 1    2
> 0.36102 0.63898
> Means:
> 1    2
> 54.619 80.094
> Variances:
> 1    2
> 34.439 34.439
>  A two-components mixture of Gaussian variables with the same variance is selected by BIC. The
> parameter estimates can be read from the summary output.
> A plot of density estimate can be obtained using the corresponding plot method:
>
> > plot(densWaiting)    The density can also be plotted together with a histogram of the observed data by using the optional
> argument data:
> > plot(densWaiting, data = faithful$waiting)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

See if the [EMCluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EMCluster/EMCluster.pdf) package suits your needs.

```
 install.packages("EMCluster")

 # excerpt from pg 12 of the EMCluster manual.
 library(EMCluster, quiet = TRUE)
 set.seed(1234)
 x <- da1$da
 ret.em <- init.EM(x, nclass = 2, method = "em.EM")
 plotem(ret.em, x)
```

If not, there's other [Model-based clustering methods](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) in R. Enjoy!